# How to count the number of occurrences in a variable using python

Tags: python, numpy, count

I imported a csv file with the variable “HEIGHT” which has 10 values.

```
HEIGHT
62
58
72
63
66
62
63
62
62
67
```

I want to use numpy and numpy only to count the number of times the value ‘62’ does not occur. The answer should be 6.

```
import numpy
import csv
with open(‘measurements.csv’),’r’) as f:
rows=f.readline()
rows=f.split(‘,’)
rows=numpy.array([rows[2:4]])
print(rows)
```

I’m a beginner python learner practicing numpy, so I am not quite sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: A very useful tool will be the [`==` operator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations). If you write something like `rows == 62`, you get back an array of the same shape of `rows` with a `True` wherever the value is `62` and `False` everywhere else. How could you use that to solve this?

Comment: _I want to use numpy and numpy only_ What does _numpy only_ mean? _so I am not quite sure how to approach this problem._ Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using numpy you can do:

```
data = np.array([62, 58, 72, 63, 66, 62, 63, 62, 62, 67])

(data != 62).sum()
```

That is, `data != 62` will make a numpy Boolean array, and `sum` will add these up, with `True` as `1`, giving the total count.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use *numpy and numpy only*,

Load the file using numpy:

```
dataset = np.loadtxt('measurements.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Seems like the height variable is in the 3rd column (index *2*). When you use `loadtxt`, you'll get a 2D array that looks like a table. You need the column with index 2, and you can then use @tom10's solution:

```
(dataset[:, 2] != 62).sum()
```

And you have a complete numpy workflow.

**Note:** Read docs to understand functions used better.

- [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)
- [Comparisons in numpy arrays](https://www.python-course.eu/numpy_masking.php) (Tutorial - opinionated!)
- [Official docs on indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)